# How to unlist two different lists of tuples to the same structure and append to file object?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have two different lists of tuples with different structure that I want to append. The first, `attribute` is a list o tuples with every value in a single tuple as string and always with a comma after the value, like this

```
[('id',), ('attr_1',), ('attr_2',), ...]
```

The second, `value` is a list of tuples where all values matching the attributes are in a single tuple and is filled with strings and numbers, like this

```
[(111, 222, 333), ('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'), ('a1', 'b2', 'c3'), ...]
```

I want to bind both objects, resulting in a file output like this

```
id; attr_1; attr_2; ...
111; aaa; a1; ...
222; bbb; b2; ...
333; ccc; c3; ...
```

I tried so far

```
attr = (list(sum(attribute, ())) )
attri = ";".join(attr)
```

which works fine for the `attribute` list, however not for `value`. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`zip`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/zip-in-python/):

```
test_tup = [(111, 222, 333), ('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'), ('a1', 'b2', 'c3')]
print(list(zip(*test_tup)))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[(111, 'aaa', 'a1'), (222, 'bbb', 'b2'), (333, 'ccc', 'c3')]
```

To write them together separated by `;`:

```
print('; '.join(' '.join(str(x) for x in i) for i in headers))
print('\n'.join('; '.join(str(x) for x in i) for i in res))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
id; attr_1; attr_2
111; aaa; a1
222; bbb; b2
333; ccc; c3
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you want to write your desired output in a csv file:

```
import pandas as pd
a = [('id',), ('attr_1',), ('attr_2',), ...]
b = [(111, 222, 333), ('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'), ('a1', 'b2', 'c3'), ...]
df = pd.DataFrame({a[i][0] : b[i] for i in range(len(a))}) # length of a and each item inside b must be same
df.to_csv(file_name, sep=';')
```

Comment: Are there any performance benefits to warrant using pandas over native python functions?

Comment: @DillonDavis The other person asked for **resulting in a file output**. As it is more viable to store the result in a csv like format, I used pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like,

```
>>> header
[('id',), ('attr_1',), ('attr_2',)]
>>> x
[(111, 222, 333), ('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'), ('a1', 'b2', 'c3')]
>>> ';'.join(x[0] for x in header)
'id;attr_1;attr_2'
>>> print('\n'.join(';'.join(str(_) for _ in y) for y in zip(*x)))
111;aaa;a1
222;bbb;b2
333;ccc;c3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't `.join` `int`s, you should convert them into `str` first, then use `zip`:

```
values = [(111, 222, 333), ('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'), ('a1', 'b2', 'c3')]
values = [tuple(str(j) for j in i) for i in values]
out = ['; '.join(i) for i in zip(*values)]
print(out) #['111; aaa; a1', '222; bbb; b2', '333; ccc; c3']
```

Optionally add `out = '\n'.join(out)` line after `out = ['; '.join(i) for i in zip(*values)]` if you wish single `str`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do join also on the second list, but you need to do it on each element of the list. F.ex by list compherension:

```
value_list = [ ";".join(i) for i in value]
```